# Factorize :hover mixin with Less

Tags: css, hover, less

I started this week with *less* style-sheet development.

My current project have many link of different colors like:

```
#dev-team a {
    color: #D09EBA;
}
#admin-team a {
    color: #0C3FDA;
}
#test-team a {
    color: #009FD1;
}
...
```

That I'm doing is to add a hover color lighten that the standart one's like:

```
#dev-team a {
    color: #D09EBA;
    &:hover{
        lighten(#D09EBA, 7%);
    }
}
#admin-team a {
    color: #0C3FDA;
    &:hover{
        lighten(#0C3FDA, 7%);
    }
}
...
```

I wonder if it's possible with less mixin or less function to avoid writing this line for each different color link I have, like a factorization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xavier's correct answer, in your case, can be made to reduce coding even further, like so:

**LESS**

```css
.team-link(@color) {
  &-team a {
    color: @color;
    &:hover{
        color: lighten(@color, 7%);
    }
  }
}
#dev {
    .team-link(#D09EBA);
}
#admin {
    .team-link(#0C3FDA);
}
#test {
    .team-link(#009FD1);
}
```

**CSS Output**

```css
#dev-team a {
  color: #d09eba;
}
#dev-team a:hover {
  color: #dcb6cb;
}
#admin-team a {
  color: #0c3fda;
}
#admin-team a:hover {
  color: #174ef2;
}
#test-team a {
  color: #009fd1;
}
#test-team a:hover {
  color: #00baf5;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use a parametric mixin http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-parametric-feature

For example, you can write your CSS like this:

```
.colored-link(@color) {
    color: @color;
    &:hover{
        color: lighten(@color, 7%);
    }
}
#dev-team a {
    .colored-link(#D09EBA);
}
#admin-team a {
    .colored-link(#0C3FDA);
}
```

The code is untested but should work.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @seven-phases-max, I missed that.